# How to add a chart to a PowerPoint slide using think-cell chart?

Tags: c#, charts, vsto, powerpoint

I am trying to use think-cell chart, a 3rd party software add-in for PowerPoint. I wanted to replace the default chart when calling the addChart() method and use the think-cell chart instead.

```
shape = MySlider.Shapes.AddChart(Microsoft.Office.Core.XlChartType.xlColumnStacked, 40, 40, 500, 500);
```

the above snippet is to add chart in slide in the PowerPoint, but it uses the default chart of the PowerPoint.

Answer (score 1):

First create a think-cell chart template (by inserting, as usual, a think-cell chart from the Elements menu into a new file, which you can save then as a template).

Then create program logic to update a copy of this template chart. You can do this either with JSON or with VBA or C# from Excel. In the Excel case, either use think-cell's UpdateChart or PresentationFromTemplate functions. For JSON and UpdateChart, you must also give the chart a name to identify it, using think-cell's menu when you select the chart, by entering the name in the "UpdateChart Name" field.

Note that our manual provides additional and up-to-date information as well as examples, https://www.think-cell.com/support/manual/introductionautomation.shtml You may also contact us directly on support(at)think-cell(dot)com.